Backing up on external exFAT HDD via USB using rsync is extremely slow (20kB/s)
I am backing up my machine on an external HDD hard-drive of 2TB formated in exFAT via USB using rsync on Ubuntu 22.04 and the file is extremely slow (sometimes stuck at 20kB/s for several seconds). How could I do to see what is the problem or speed things up?
The model of the HDD (Western Digital) is the following:
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep -i number
        Model Number:       WDC WD20SDRW-11VUUS0


What model is this external disk?

@harrymc thanks for your comment. I edited the question accordingly. Is this what you asked?

It's quite possible that this is the correct behavior of this disk.
Several sources say that your disk model is
Shingled magnetic recording (SMR),
which means that it has a faster buffer that when full would need
flushing out to the slower part. On some models with a large buffer
the flushing can take a very long time.
Write speed for SMR disks is optimal when the disk is wiped clean,
but could become very slow if it's quite full or the data size
exceeds that of the buffer.
You could wipe the disk before every backup operation to achieve
maximal write speed, or you'll just need to give the disk the time
it needs to complete the operation.
You may read more about it in the following articles :

Buyer beware—that 2TB-6TB “NAS” drive you’ve been eyeing might be SMR
Manfred Berger - HGST SMR - OpenZFS European Conference 2015
The buffer flush of SMR may take hours on some models and conditions.
WD Red SMR Lawsuit Pays Out Pennies in Settlement Damages
WD lost a lawsuit because it didn't specify whether disks were SMR
or not (and it still doesn't, I believe)
WD20SDRW-11VUUS0 HDD Firmware Repair ID info

